# Completely remove page numbers

Tags: page-numbering

I'm trying to create some custom graph paper for myself. However, I don't want page numbers on it, so I was wondering how to completely remove page numbers. My code is

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}

\SetBgContents%
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw [line width=0.3pt,color=gray,step=0.5cm] (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(The rectangle is just to have something on the page.)

Thanks!

**Edit:** I found the solution on my own and posted it as an answer. I am open to better solutions.

Comment: Any reason you can't use `\pagestyle{empty}` in the preamble? Works for me

Comment: @Au101, I actually found that solution just now and posted it as an answer. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this answer (of course) 5 minutes after I posted this question, even though I'd spent a while looking for it. =)

I added the line `\thispagestyle{empty}`

for the code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}

\SetBgContents%
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw [line width=0.3pt,color=gray,step=0.5cm] (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which worked perfectly.

As Au101 mentioned in the comments, it is probably preferable to move `\thispagestyle` to the preamble:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}

\SetBgContents%
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw [line width=0.3pt,color=gray,step=0.5cm] (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And then put the line in the main body of the document for any special cases where you want the page numbers again.

Comment: Again, I'd set it globally in the preamble, and then use `\thispagestyle` to adjust as needs be in the document. Doesn't sound like you'd need to do much adjusting in this document, but as a general rule, set the default page style for your documents in the preamble

Comment: @Au101, okay, thank you; I did so. If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Hey, don't worry about it, your answer is close enough that I'd just edit it as a second option and get yourself "self-learner"

Comment: @Au101, okay; thanks for your help!